# Laurent polynomial Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field, $ \mathbb{R} = \mathbb{F}[X,X^{-1}]$ the ring of Laurent polynomials over $\mathbb{F}$

> > a) find the group of units in R.
> >
> > b) find an Euclidean norm in R.

so for a, I understand the units are $uX^{\pm i}$ where $ u \in F, u\neq 0$.

can you give me a hint about b?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** Prove that any $f\in R$ can be represented as $f=x^{-n}g$ for $g\in F[x]$. Then rewrite the condition that $f$ is a unit as a condition for polynomials.

As for b), as you know, $\deg$ is an Euclidean norm for $F[x]$. Try to find its analogue for $R$. For $f=x^{-n}g$ with $g\in F[x], g(0)\not=0$, what should it be equal to?

Comment: Then you are right.

Answer (score 1):

This may well be overkill, but it is a result of Motzkin and Samuel that any localization of a Euclidean domain is Euclidean.  A proof is given in Theorem 2.33 of [this paper of mine](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/OrdinalInvariant.pdf).

Since you say you want a *hint*: take the Euclidean function $\operatorname{deg}$ you know on $F[x]$, write an element $f$ of $F[X,X^{-1}]$ as a unit times an element $g$ which is not divisible by $x$, and try to show that $f \mapsto \operatorname{deg}(g)$ is a Euclidean function.  (In other words, what 8k14 said!)

Comment: Pardon? Is there a *theorem* saying that any localization of a Euclidean ring is Euclidean? I've always thought that this is an exercise.

Comment: @YACP: Motzkin's 1948 paper does not have any formally stated theorems but devotes a short section to localized Euclidean functions.  The result is "Proposition 7" in Samuel's 1971 Euclidean paper.  So perhaps "result of Motzkin-Samuel" would be more faithful to their papers.  Theorem 2.33 in my paper squeezes a bit more information (on the **Euclidean order type**) out of this construction, but I suppose that I decided that a result that appeared in the two foundational papers in the theory of transfinite Euclidean rings was worth calling a theorem.

Comment: In all this business, would it help to assume that $deg(0)=-\infty$, so that we won't have to keep saying "nonzero" more times than really needed?